# Pc Chrome website zooms in when submit button is clicked

Tags: html, css

Im making a website for my tech class and i have put a submit button in but as said in the title when i click my submit button my page zooms in, i am on pc not mobile. heres my code for any interested

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <div id="header"><head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title> this is a Title </title>
        <h1> GIVE ME A MILLION</h1>
        <li> <a href="cart"><img id="cart" src="shopping_cart_PNG66.png" width="10%"></a> </li>
        </head>
    </div>
    <body>
        <div id="Body">
            <div id="Navbar"> 
                <ul>
                    <nav>
                    <li><a href="aboutrevision">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactrevision">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    </nav>
                </ul>
                <form>
                    <label for="Fname">first name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="Fname" name="Fname"><br>
                    <label for="Lname">last name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="Lname" name="Lname"><br>
                    <label for="Money">Give me Money:</label>
                    <select id="Money" name="Money">
                    <option value="1Million">1 Million </option>
                    <option value="1Billion">1 Billion </option>
                    <option value="1Trillion">1 trillion </option>
                    <option value="1Quadrilion">1 Quadrilion </option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </form>
                
            <br><br><br><br><br>this is a body<br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </body>
        <div id="footer">
            <footer>
                <p>This is a footer</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
</html>
```

My css

```
* {margin: 0;}
    body {background-color: aqua; text-align: center;font-size: 300%;}
    #header {background-color: blue;padding: 35px;text-align: left;font-size: 80%;}
        Nav {background-color: yellow;padding: 15px;font-size: 100%;}
            ul {text-align: center; list-style-type:none;}
                li {display: inline-block; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; padding: 30px;}
                    footer{background-color: lime;padding: 35px;text-align: center;font-size: 100%;}
                        #cart {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
                            nav a {text-decoration: none;padding: 20px;}
                                nav a:hover {color: red; background-color: aliceblue;}
```

ive tried using meta port, looking on w3schools and ive tried moving it around, none of these have fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code and tried it. cannot replicate the zoom you mention. But I guess you means the page scroll to top when button click. That is a normal behaviour when a form is submitted. And I need to bring out that the structure of your html is not standard. `<div>` should only place inside `<body>`. And `<head>` is not allow inside `<div>`. FYI, `<head>` is different from `<header>`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but ive tested the website on my pc at home and have realised it only happens on my school laptop, its a dell latitude 3310, if this could provide anything more help that would be appreciated